# Integrate Payment Gateway into NativeScript App

Tags: javascript, payment-gateway, nativescript

i am quite new to Mobile App Development, Payment Gateway implementation and NativeScript itself. Now i shall integrate an IPG into a Mobile App build with NativeScript to allow the user to buy goods via the Application (it is already possible to do so via the Website). I do not have any information regarding supported payment methods yet.

Whenever coding something i do have the opportunites to either write it on my own or use an existing open-source API. I've decided to try an open-source API to make it work.

My Problem is that i don't really know where to start. I have been doing some research on "how nativescript works" and Payment Gateway itself. Basically any JavaScript code is going to work with NativeScript, so any open-source API for IPG working with JavaScript should do it for my Application, right? Since i did not find any open-source API's for NativeScript itself, i started looking for any JavaScript API. Sadly, all if found was an API of telecash (https://www.telecash.de/produkte-services/e-commerce/support-fuer-entwickler/downloads-handbuecher/) (watch out, thats a german side), whose documentation seems quite fine, but it did not seem open-source.

So my Question(s):

Can anyone tell me a little bit about any experience you might have with that topic (perhaps just a link or a tip)? Maybe there is even another thing that i should start with that i have forgotten? And i think i did not understand the difference (if there is one) between Payment Gateways itself and IPG. Maybe someone can help me out on that.

I can not post code here since i am still on the "research"-phase (have been for quite a long time), but I can not see any progress within it so I am counting on your help. Feel free to correct me if I did a mistake or understood something wrong I mentioned here. :-)

Best regards.

Comment: Are you trying to offer in-app purchases or replicate some e-commerce offering you have on a website?